# How can I configure phpstorm so default behaviour is to ignore VCS?

Tags: git, phpstorm

If I open a folder/project with Phpstorm and that folder contains a git repo, phpstorm with automatically assume I want it to manage the repo.
I prefer terminal + git for VCS so typically I just go into `settings` > `version control` and disable/unregister git VCS root.
I would like to configure phpstorm so that its default behaviour is to ignore any VCS it detects and not to try and manage VCS.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to use Git within Phpstorm, simply disable or uninstall the Git plugin:

`Settings > Plugins > Git Integration` - uncheck

Afaik, there's no way to explicitly disable the automatic VCS root include.